# Is there an exact replacement for the old functional.curry?

Tags: python

I am trying to run this snippet from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-prog3.html on a python 2.6 runtime.

```
from functional import *

taxcalc = lambda income,rate,deduct: (income-(deduct))*rate

taxCurry = curry(taxcalc)
taxCurry = taxCurry(50000)
taxCurry = taxCurry(0.30)
taxCurry = taxCurry(10000)
print "Curried taxes due =",taxCurry

print "Curried expression taxes due =", \
      curry(taxcalc)(50000)(0.30)(10000)
```

Ok, so I understand from http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0309/ that functional is renamed to functools and curry to partial but just doing the renames doesn't help. I get the error:

```
taxCurry = taxCurry(50000)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

The following does work but do I really have to change it so much?

```
from functools import partial

taxcalc = lambda income,rate,deduct: (income-(deduct))*rate

taxCurry = partial(taxcalc)
taxCurry = partial(taxCurry, 50000)
taxCurry = partial(taxCurry, 0.30)
taxCurry = partial(taxCurry, 10000)
print "Curried taxes due =", taxCurry()

print "Curried expression taxes due =", \
      taxcalc(50000, 0.30, 10000)
```

Is there a better way of preserving the mechanics of the original example? Lastly was the original example truly currying or just partial application? (as per http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk)

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is it this particular example important one? Or do you have some real example which could reveal some usefulness of currying? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the reason why they changed it is because Python is dynamically typed. This means that it would be really hard to debug the original `curry` code if anything goes wrong - much harder than in a language like Haskell where you would directly get a nice type error. So I think it was a reasonable decision to replace it with the more explicit `partial` version (looks more pythonic to me).

Your example is also a bit strange, since you just reassigning the partially applied functions to the same name. Normally the partially applied function would be given to another function. At least that is the only reasonable use case in Python I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `curry` in the [`toolz` project](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/) should be a drop-in replacement.

```
$ pip install toolz
>>> from toolz import curry
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [an implementation of a curry decorator](https://gist.github.com/JulienPalard/021f1c7332507d6a494b) that works well:

```
def curry(func):
    """
    Decorator to curry a function, typical usage:

    >>> @curry
    ... def foo(a, b, c):
    ...    return a + b + c

    The function still work normally:
    >>> foo(1, 2, 3)
    6

    And in various curried forms:
    >>> foo(1)(2, 3)
    6
    >>> foo(1)(2)(3)
    6

    This also work with named arguments:
    >>> foo(a=1)(b=2)(c=3)
    6
    >>> foo(b=1)(c=2)(a=3)
    6
    >>> foo(a=1, b=2)(c=3)
    6
    >>> foo(a=1)(b=2, c=3)
    6

    And you may also change your mind on named arguments,
    But I don't know why you may want to do that:
    >>> foo(a=1, b=0)(b=2, c=3)
    6

    Finally, if you give more parameters than expected, the exception
    is the expected one, not some garbage produced by the currying
    mechanism:

    >>> foo(1, 2)(3, 4)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       ...
    TypeError: foo() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
    """
    def curried(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) + len(kwargs) >= func.__code__.co_argcount:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return (lambda *args2, **kwargs2:
                curried(*(args + args2), **dict(kwargs, **kwargs2)))
    return curried


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```